# add animation to a vue component when store value is updated

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am new in using `VueJs`,
I use `Vuex` `store` to handle my component data, when I do `mutation`/data update to a particular object in my store data which is a `nested` `object`, I want to add `animation` to the component that reference to that particular object to indicate the change.

is this possible? 
is using watcher a good idea, it could be many components?
or the updated in component hooks enough?

Comment: It is possible, but paste your complete html and js of what you want to animate

Comment: hello Georgi, I already resolved my issue using the `updated` life cycle hook. Thanks a lot for responding. I will post my resolution here so that others can use it as well..